# Overlay image on FFMPEG running on and on

Tags: ffmpeg, image-processing, overlay

I wanted to overlay images on my video but no impact to any audio. My video is of length 01:32:34 and my below script continue running from 3 hrs and then I closed it. Looks some issue. Please can you advise.

```
    ffmpeg 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/test_video.mp4 
-i D:/uploads/Image1.jpg 
-i D:/uploads/Image2.jpg 
-filter_complex  "[0][1]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,2238.716831,2238.716831)'[v1];
[v1][2]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,2238.716831,2471.229935)'[v2]" 
-map "[v2]" -map 0:a D:\ffmpeg_output\output.mp4
```

Kind Regards,

Comment: Copy and paste the complete output of `ffmpeg -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/test_video.mp4`

Comment: Very sorry for late replying. It worked in the next run without any issues. Not sure what happened at the first time. It was like reading image binary file. Its fine now. Many Many thanks for your response.